# Accessing Azure Storage through Unity

Tags: c#, azure, unity-game-engine, azure-storage

I am working on a project where I need to create a online HighScore Leaderboard(best score achieved) for every level in the game. Example: LevelName: A2, Score: 10.33, User: "SomePlayer".

So, since I have 130$/month due to my MSDN subscription, I have been researching about table storages and managed to setup one and I think it fills my needs.

My next step was to get an Azure function running to communicate with this table.

My question is, is it possible to access a Azure Function through Unity? Or am I overthinking this? Is there any simpler method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any simpler method?

It seems that you want to use Azure function to operate the Azure storage table. Maybe we could use [Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-value-prop) to do that. I also find a [Highscore demo features](https://github.com/Unity3dAzure/AppServicesDemo) on the github.

> **Highscore demo features**
>
> - Client-directed login with Facebook
> - Insert Highscore
> - Update Highscore
> - Read list of Highscores using infinite scrolling (hall of fame)
> - Query for today's top ten highscores (daily leaderboard)
> - Query for username (user's scores)

Comment: Thanks for the input, my project is not mobile oriented but that Github project seems intresting. I will definetely take a look!